# Using HandlerInterceptor to modify RestController response output

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot REST service where the endpoints all return JSON messages of the following format:

```
{
  status: {
    code: XXXX
  },
  data : {
    something: YYYY
  }
}
```

I want to have a common point in my code to add in a "description" associated with the "code" above:

```
{
  status: {
    code: XXXX,
    description: "Hello"
  },
  data : {
    something: YYYY
  }
}
```

and I would like to use HandlerInterceptor to basically do the following in the postHandle phase:

1. Get the response JSON message
2. Use JsonNode to get the code, lookup the corresponding description value by calling a remote service, and
3. Modify the response by inserting the description value into the JsonNode and returning the resulting string value of the JsonNode

Understanding how to get the JSON response from the ModelandView object in the postHandle method is proving to be a challenge though. My controller classes are all just annotated with @RestController and I don't have Model or View classes. The sample codes that I've come across mostly just add some logging functions and the modelandView.addObject() method doesn't seem to do what I want.

Can I get a pointer on how to achieve what I need, which is to clobber the response on its way out?

I would like to avoid using Servlet Filters as I need access to the Spring context to perform the lookups that I need and as far as I know, Filter classes are invoked beyond the reaches of Spring context.

Comment: You are returning something from your controller, then why would you need to modify it afterwards...

Comment: Late requirements to add a description field based on the code field against a tight timeline. This is the fastest way that I can think of doing it.

Comment: Why would that be faster then wrapping your original object into a dto/proxy add the field and let Jackson do the rest (no pun intended).

Comment: Well, we kind of ended up doing it the way that you described. We basically added a @ControllerAdvice class to add the information that we required. Thanks!